# Как свернуть только дочернюю форму?

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку свернуть свернулась только дочерняя форма, а родительская осталась(то есть чтоб не сворачивались 2 формы).
Сворачиваю таким образом:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ticket_form.ActiveForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

вот здесь я из родительской формы перехожу в другую форму тем временем они обе открыты:

```
try
        {
            if (act_table == 1)
            {
                ticket_form f = new ticket_form();
                f.button3.Visible = false;
                if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Add_ticket(f.textBox4.Text, f.textBox5.Text);
                    Get_Tickets();
                }
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
форма администратора это родительская форма начальная, а форма добавления записей - вторичная дочерняя форма.

Comment: в коде сворачивание 1 формы, а не двух, не понятно, о чем речь. создайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @aepot получается я от родительской формы перехожу в дочернюю форму через кнопку и саму дочернюю форму сворачиваю но в результате сворачиваются 2 формы

Comment: @aepot я добавил конкретики в свой вопрос надеюсь понятно все показал

Comment: Так вторая форма - диалог, смысл сворачивать ее и оставлять заблокированной старшую форму? Чтобы получить раздельное управление формами, надо чтобы дочерняя форма перестала быть диалогом.

Comment: понял, спасибо за совет